# GStreamer Editing Service for Rust / How to specify encoder settings

Tags: encoding, rust, gstreamer, profile

I'm new to gstreamer-rs. I try to render a video using GStreamer Editing Service. At the moment I am using the example code for encoding profiles as follows:

```rust
let p = gstreamer_editing_services::Pipeline::new();
let t = gstreamer_editing_services::Timeline::new_audio_video();
p.set_timeline(&t);
let l = t.append_layer();

// Every audiostream piped into the encodebin should be encoded using vorbis.
let audio_profile = gstreamer_pbutils::EncodingAudioProfileBuilder::new()
    .format(&gstreamer::Caps::new_simple("audio/x-opus", &[]))
    .presence(0)
    .build()?;

// Every videostream piped into the encodebin should be encoded using theora.
let video_profile = gstreamer_pbutils::EncodingVideoProfileBuilder::new()
    .format(&gstreamer::Caps::new_simple("video/x-h264", &[]))
    .presence(0)
    .build()?;

// All streams are then finally combined into a matroska container.
let container_profile = gstreamer_pbutils::EncodingContainerProfileBuilder::new()
    .name("container")
    .format(&gstreamer::Caps::new_simple("video/x-matroska", &[]))
    .add_profile(&(video_profile))
    .add_profile(&(audio_profile))
    .build()?;

p.set_render_settings("file:///tmp/my.mp4", &container_profile);
```

The code is working; but I do not have any clue on how to enforce specific settings. Maybe someone can help.

- How do you set things like bitrate, framerate and quality options for the audio and video encoder?
- How do you define a specific encoder (like nvenc/nvh264enc for h264 video)?

Comment: The GStreamer documentation includes an [example](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/pbutils/encoding-profile.html#example-using-an-encoder-preset-with-a-profile) in C that sets a specific encoder and bitrate using a [`Preset`](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/stable/latest/docs/gstreamer/struct.Preset.html).

Comment: Thank you; but the next question is: How do you instanciate a preset in gstreamer-rs. There is no new()-method and no factory... or do i miss something?

Comment: In the C example, they use `gst_element_factory_make`, which creates a `GstElement` and cast it to `GstPreset`, so I'd try the same thing in Rust.